# Как сгенерировать случайное время в диапазоне?

Tags: c#, время

Как можно сгенерировать время суток, к примеру 23:55 или 17:30, только чтобы не генерировалось от 00:00 до 05:30 ? 4-я цифра будет только 5 или 0

Comment: Точнее, так: взять случайное число от 67 до 286 включительно, поделить на 12 — это будут часы, взять остаток от деления на 12 и домножить на 5 — это будут минуты

Comment: не проще взять случайное число от 535 (05:3Х) до 235 (23:5Х), а икс случайно 0 или 5?

Comment: @AndreyIvasko не проще, потому что может получиться 05:95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть использовать [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)? 
Один из конструкторов принимает часы, минуты и секунды. Их то и рандомим через Random как надо.

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(rnd.Next(0, 6), rnd.Next(0,55)/5*5, 0);
Console.WriteLine($"{ts.Hours}:{ts.Minutes}")
```

Comment: 1) `rnd.Next(0,55)` нужно сменить на `rnd.Next(0,60)`, иначе 55 минут никогда не наступят. 2) В задаче стоит время до 5:30, а в вашем случае может и 5:55 получится. 3) В случае ограничения по времени до 5:30 появляется одна маленькая неприятность: вероятность получения какого-либо значения в интервале от 5:00 до 5:30 выше, чем в других интервалах.

Comment: 1. Да, ошибся с граничными значениями. 
2. Угу, невнимательность)

Comment: А Вы внимательно читали вопрос? Впрочем, автор, вероятно, тоже особо не вдавался ;)  `00:00 - 05:30` - **запрещённый** диапазон

Comment: @MBo. Внимательно. Автор почему-то меняет вопрос, после каждого ответа.

Comment: @Александр Ли Странно, в правки я заглядывал, но там это не отражено

Comment: @MBo, странно... заработался я что ли...

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий ответ неверен. Спасибо, @John!

Подойдем иначе. 
Нужно указать время в диапазоне от 00:00 до 05:30 с шагом в 5 минут. Общее кол-во отрезков в 5 минут = 5 * 12 + 6 = 66 отрезков. 
Тогда случайно генерируем число от 0 до 66. Умножаем его на 5. И создаем TimeSpan c этим числом в качестве минут.

```
        var parts = rnd.Next(0, 66);
        var minutes = parts * 5;
        var ts = new TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"{ts.Hours}:{ts.Minutes}");
```

Если нужен диапазон исключающий время с 00:00 до 05:30, то необходимо просто сделать сдвиг и изменить максимальное случайно число.

```
//222 - кол-во 5-минутных отрезков в диапазоне от 5:30 до 00:00
    var parts = rnd.Next(0, 222);
// прибавляем сдвиг
    var minutes = parts * 5 + 66 * 5;
    var ts = new TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0);
    Console.WriteLine($"{ts.Hours}:{ts.Minutes}");
```